# How to change Google Maps marker's visibility dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use [this directive](http://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/docs/index.html) for Google Maps in my Angular project.

```
<map center="50.4501, 30.5234" zoom="11" style="height: 100%" data-tap-disabled="true">
    <marker ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 50" icon="img/marker.png" position="{{item.coords}}" eventid={{item.id}} on-click="go()">
    </marker>
</map>
```

I need to change visibility of markers with function, that returns true / false.

I was trying to do this with ng-if="isVisible()", ng-show="isVisible()", by setting marker's property visible="isVisible()" - nothing works.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) library specifically designed for calling various UI related API's.

After embedding this library you can call all the API's in the same way as you do while using Google maps. For example to control the visibility of a particular marker use the following code:

```
<map center="[40.74, -74.18]">
  <marker
      position="[40.76, -74.16]"
      title="Hello Marker"
      animation="Animation.BOUNCE"
      draggable="true"
      visible="true"
      icon="beachflag.png"></marker>
</map>
```